# data is not retrieved from firestore when using queries for filter in firestoreConnect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Data is not retrieved from Firestore when using queries for filter in `firestoreconnect`. Following is my code. Can someone help me on this?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        joblists: state.firestore.ordered.Jobs
    };
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    firestoreConnect([{
        collection: 'Jobs',
        orderBy: ['postedon','desc'],
        where: ['postedby', '==', "Employer1"]
    }])
)(EmpJob);
```

In the console, I get:

```
firestore:
composite: undefined
data: {Jobs: {…}}
errors: {byQuery: {…}, allIds: Array(1)}
listeners: {byId: {…}, allIds: Array(2)}
ordered: {Jobs: Array(10)}
queries: {}
status: {requesting: {…}, requested: {…}, timestamps: {…}}
__ .  proto__: Object
joblist: {joblists: Array(6)}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the [`compose`](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) function is important. `firestoreConnect([...])` should be the first parameter passed in, followed by `connect(mapStateToProps)`.

As an example, see the bottom example on https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/api/firestoreConnect.html.